# web_submit_data function passes the values in URL format instead of HTML format

Tags: correlation, loadrunner, hyperion

I am working on Hyperion FR reports (version 11.1.2.3 ) using load runner 11.5. The issue I am facing is with respect to a dynamic value "sso_token" that needs to be correlated. This "sso_token" is being passed in HTML mode in some requests and URL mode in others.

I have captured the dynamic values using the below syntax

```
web_reg_save_param("ssotoken_noencod", "LB=<token><![CDATA[", "RB=]]></token><user", LAST);
web_reg_save_param("C_ssotoken1", "LB=<token><![CDATA[", "RB=]]></token><user", "CONVERT=HTML_TO_URL", LAST);
```

In the `web_submit_data` request, the parameter substitution in the replay logs shows the HTML value substituted for "`sotoken_noencod` which is as expected.

However, advance trace shows that the URL value is passed in the actual request that gets submitted.

I have worked on earlier versions of LR and Hyperion, but we never faced issue of this sort. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It will be hard to answer your question on SO. I suggest you try posting it on the public "HP LoadRunner Support forum".

Answer (score 0):

run the script some time. gather info which request is getting URL or HTML mode value and then you can create condition if else.....and use the HTML or URL mode value.